# SQLite: remove duplicate rows when entire row is not unique

Tags: sqlite, view, no-duplicates

I'm creating an SQLite view to track customer emails and their accounts.  There are some customers who created multiple accounts with the same email address.  Using SQLite, is there a way to restrict the view to return each email only once regardless of how many accounts that individual has?  I am not concerned which account gets discarded (i.e. Jim1 or Jim2).

```
AccountName    Email
Jim1           Jim@example.com
Jim2           Jim@example.com
Shania         Sh@example.com
```

The view would return:

```
AccountName    Email
Jim1           Jim@example.com
Shania         Sh@example.com
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Group the results by `Email`, then take the first or last corresponding record:

```
  SELECT Email
  ,      MIN(AccountName) AS Account
    FROM table
GROUP BY Email;
```

**UPDATE**:
Note that you can add a unique constraint to the email column, so that SQLite errors out if you try to insert the same value a second time:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
( id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
, email       TEXT    NOT NULL UNIQUE COLLATE NOCASE
, accountname TEXT    NOT NULL        COLLATE NOCASE
);
```

The [UNIQUE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints) clause on the `email` column indicates that no two rows can contain the same value.
The [COLLATE NOCASE](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) clause causes SQLite to compare values in that row in a case-insensitive manner (so 'EMAIL' and 'eMail' would count as equal).